# JS function enters an infinite loop when I have more values in holidays array

Tags: javascript

I have a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1z9mvLy/

```
function check_previous_business_date(date, timezone) {
      const startDate = new Date(luxon.DateTime.fromISO(date).setZone(timezone));
      const todayTimeStamp = +new Date(startDate); // Unix timestamp in milliseconds
      const oneDayTimeStamp = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // Milliseconds in a day
      const diff = todayTimeStamp - oneDayTimeStamp;
      const yesterdayDate = new Date(diff);
      const yesterdayString = yesterdayDate.getFullYear()
         + '-' + (yesterdayDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + yesterdayDate.getDate();
      for (startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1);
        !startDate.getDay() || startDate.getDay() === 6 ||
        federalHolidays.includes(startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]) ||
        federalHolidays.includes(yesterdayString);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1)
      ) { 
      }

      return startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    }
const federalHolidays= [
  '2019-05-27',
  '2019-09-02',
  '2019-10-14',
  '2019-11-11'
];
console.log('Prev. day of 2019-05-28 is ',check_previous_business_date('2019-05-28T07:00:00.000Z', 'America/New_York'));
console.log('Prev. day of 2019-06-20 is ',check_previous_business_date('2019-06-20T07:00:00.000Z', 'America/New_York'));
console.log('Prev. day of 2019-06-24 is ',check_previous_business_date('2019-06-24T07:00:00.000Z', 'America/New_York'));
```

When I have just a few records in my federalHolidays array, it would work absolutely fine. But the problem is when the size of federalHolidays array increases, it enters an infinite loop.

Please checkout the fiddle.

Comment: Why use a `for` statement like that there? A `while` would be more appropriate and more readable.

Comment: Add the example for federalHolidays that triggers it to go into an infinite loop

Comment: In general, what with all that mess inside the `for`? It's rather suspicious to have a `for` with an empty body and all that stuff in the termination condition.

Comment: `federalHolidays.includes(yesterdayString)` will return true all the time if it returns true once, because 'yesterdayString' does'nt change

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to get previous working date for any given date. Working date is always a weekday and does not come in federalHolidays.

Answer (score 0):

This is your loop:

```
  for (startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1);
    !startDate.getDay() || startDate.getDay() === 6 ||
    federalHolidays.includes(startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]) ||
    federalHolidays.includes(yesterdayString);
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1)
  ) { 
  }
```

The problem is that `yesterdayString` never changes in the loop, so if it happens to be in `federalHolidays`, then you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: I see. So you mean if it's a federal holiday just return last exit from the for loop?

Comment: @lalabhatt You will not need to check for yesterday whether it was a business day inside the loop. You could check for that before the loop and if it happens to be a holiday, then we know that the previous business day must be before yesterday, so you need to start the loop from two days ago backwards.